# Two OpenVPN tunnels to different networks configuration setup to work simultaneously for Linux

Tags: linux, openvpn, tunneling

I have 1 machine that has OpenVPN tunnel setup with 1 external network computer. Now i want to add another external network computer with a new tunnel.

**Config file for currently operating tunnel**

```
client
;dev tap
dev tun
;dev-node MyTap
;proto tcp
proto udp
;remote 99.99.99.98 1194
remote mywebsite.com 1194
remote 99.99.99.98 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194
;remote-random
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
;user nobody
;group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]
;mute-replay-warnings
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/client.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/client.key
ns-cert-type server
;tls-auth ta.key 1
;cipher x
comp-lzo
verb 3
;mute 20
```

This is VPN tunnel configuration for currently working tunnel. Now i am trying to create another tunnel that uses its own ca.crt, client.crt and client.key

**This is another config file for second tunnel**

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 88.88.88.88
port 1000
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert 207.crt
key 207.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

1. I have tried to add the setup to the same config file but with no
   luck. Is this even possible to add another details to same config
   file or creating a new config file is a must?
2. If this is really not the way to go what other options there are?

[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS8qZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate configuration file and instance of OpenVPN for each connection. The Debian package (possibly similar on other Linux distributions) starts an instance of OpenVPN for every config file in / etc / OpenVPN. The routes for each connection must not conflict.